# Formating number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to "format" numbers. For example, if I am 25.120006 I want to get a result of 25.12.
This is my js program.

```
var amount = process.argv[2];

console.log(formatAmount(amount));

function formatAmount(amount)
 {
    if (!amount || !amount.length) return amount;
    return !amount.split(".")[1]
    ? amount + ".00"
    : amount.split(".")[1].length === 1
        ? amount + "0"
        : amount;

   }
```

I am calling "formatAmount" from another function, which looks like:

```
var cartSubtotalExtracted = process.argv[2];
var TaxExtracted = process.argv[3];
var TotalExtracted = process.argv[4];

console.log(ValidateTotal(cartSubtotalExtracted, TaxExtracted, TotalExtracted));

function ValidateTotal(cartSubtotalExtracted, TaxExtracted, TotalExtracted)
{
   console.log(formatAmount(parseFloat(cartSubtotalExtracted) + parseFloat(TaxExtracted)));
   if (parseFloat(cartSubtotalExtracted) + parseFloat(TaxExtracted) == 
  formatAmount(parseFloat(TotalExtracted)))
   {
      return "Total updated correctly";
   }
   else {
       return "Total not updated correctly";
    }
   }
```

I am getting an error which says:

^ReferenceError: formatAmount is not defined.

Not sure where I am going wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `(25.120006).toFixed(2)==25.12 //true`

Comment: You need to import your `formatAmount` function, the code doesn't have access to it. Assuming it's two separate files.